# How to use data attribute to format a DateTimeOffset property in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, annotations

I have a C# class which is used as a API json response.  I have some properties defined as DateTimeOffset.

```
public DateTimeOffset Time1 { get; set; }
public DateTimeOffset Time2 { get; set; }
```

The client receives the format as: `2024-01-02T15:26:13+00:00`
but the required format is: `2011-01-25T11:53:22.010Z`

Initially, I thought of storing as string doing format conversion using ToString() but as some of the properties are used in the program for date calculation, I cannot convert all to string.

I saw online that there are attributes that can be used on DateTime but I cannot find one for DateTimeOffset.

How do I use annotation to convert the format for DateTimeOffset ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think an annotation is the way to go? Are you open to different approaches? What json lib is in use? System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft?

Comment: @Fildor Newonsoft.  Annotation because I saw it was possible for DateTime.  Yes, very open to any working solution.  I think I saw one that say to write some converters but I couldn't find it again.

Comment: I saw a vote to close my question, reason being need more clarify.  Is it not clear ?  I want to know how I can annotate the DateTimeOffset property, if it's possible.  Please don't close my question.  Thanks.